# Force Android 6.x Marshmallow to use WiFi connection even without internet access

Tags: android, networking, connection, wifi, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am working on a App and I need to talk to my router.
I need to download a file from the router with his `local ip`. If the router has no internet access, Android tries to download the file via `mobile network`.

Is there a way to force Android to use `WiFi` even when there is no internet access?
(its a new feature of Android `Marshmallow` to show WiFi but using mobile network).
The file is not accessible from `WAN` only from `LAN`.

I can force it, when I disable mobile network or turn on airplane mode with WiFi enabled, but this isn't an option. I need to force it programmatically for this specific download.

Comment: I don't have time to distill a complete example here, but you can bind Sockets to a given Network, or even bind a whole process, using [bindProcessToNetwork] (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#bindProcessToNetwork(android.net.Network)).

Comment: the bindProcessToNetwork requires api level 23. I will try to use connectivityManager.startUsingNetworkFeature(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE, "enableHIPRI"); but with WiFi, maybe this will help.

Comment: Of course it requires API level 23... and the title of your question says "Marshmallow," no? Do you need to correct your question?

Comment: yea I am not sure because it just happened with marshmallow, I could check if it is 6.0 and then use this methode.

Comment: okay documentation of startUsingNetworkFeature says: In M, and above, this method is unsupported and will throw UnsupportedOperationException if called.

Comment: Have You got a solution to this? I have the same issue but only on 6.0.  6.0.1 is working fine.

Comment: @Lonergan6275 Please try this non-rooted solution [http://stackoverflow.com/a/40733515/4206925](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40733515/4206925)

Comment: @MewX how do you see this as a suitable solution? How can you 1) inform users to take these steps and 2) expect every affected user to do it. I solved the problem by using `bindProcessToNetwork(Network network)`